# Using only an array of ids as value with react-select

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to use react-select wit an array of ids like [2,4] while manipulating a data Array like that :

```
[
    { value:1, label:"item1" },
    { value:2, label:"item2" },
    { value:3, label:"item3" },
    { value:4, label:"item4" },
]
```

I can't find in the docs how to customise those things.

Comment: Means you want to show 2 & 4 as a options, correct?

Comment: Why don't you filter first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map loop to create options for react-select.

```
const datas =  [2,4];
datas.map((d) => {return { value: d, label: d }})
```

Demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-0tdlq

Comment: I think the answer is correct, it's just the question wasn't well enough prepared ^^'